# How to provide a list of textboxes and file input textboxes based on 2 arrays

Tags: php

i have 2 arrays - Array $doc_list_submitted for a list of docs a user have submitted and $listDocToProvide for a list of docs a user need to provide.

i need to list all docs provided in a textbox and with it a file input textbox if the user want to edit the file uploaded and other file input textboxes for the user to upload files not yet uploaded.

Here is what i have so far:

```
<?php
//list of doc to provide
$listDocToProvide  = clients::recupereListDocToProvide($projet_id);

//list of docs a user have submitted
$doc_list_submitted  = clients::recupereListDocSubmitted($client_projet_id);

//categorise $doc_list_submitted par doc_type_id
$result = array();
foreach ($doc_list_submitted as $element) {
    $result[$element['DOC_CLIENT_ID']][] = $element;
}

$iDocsx = 0;
foreach ($result as $key=>$row)
{
?>
    <input type="text" id="docfile" name="docfile[]" value="<?php echo ($result[$iDocsx]['DOC_CLIENT_NOM']); ?>" >
    <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
    <input type="file" id="docfile" name="docfileUpload[]" value="<?php echo basename($result[$iDocsx]['CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC']); ?>" >
<?php
    $iDocsx++;
                }
?>
```

I get the list of docs submitted, now i need to put textboxes for docs not yet uploaded. I have spend a whole night on this but i have not been able to do it. I need to list each file under its category like this:

Cat 1:

```
Uploaded : File 1 / File 2
Need : Textbox 1 / Textbox 2 / Textbox 3
```

Cat 2:

```
Uploaded : File 1
Need : Textbox 1 / Textbox 2
```

Could somebody please assist me.

Here is the array $doc_list_submitted:

```
[1101] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 6301
                [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 8701
                [CLIENT_ID] => 4401
                [PROJET_ID] => 4101
                [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1101
                [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => upload/doc_client_document/test 1.txt
                [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC_REF] => 
                [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_QTY] => 
                [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Lettre de référence bancaire
            )
    )

[901] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 6401
                [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 8701
                [CLIENT_ID] => 4401
                [PROJET_ID] => 4101
                [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => upload/doc_client_document/test 2.txt
                [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_QTY] => 
                [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
            )
    )
```

Here is the array $listDocToProvide:

```
[1101] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 4301
                [PROJET_ID] => 4101
                [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1101
                [DOC_CLIENT_NUM] => 2
                [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Lettre de référence bancaire
            )
    )

[901] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 4401
                [PROJET_ID] => 4101
                [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                [DOC_CLIENT_NUM] => 3
                [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code you have same id for file and textbox change it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="doctext" name="docfile[]" value="<?php echo ($result[$iDocsx]['doc_name']); ?>" >
       echo "br";
<input type="file" id="docfile" name="docfileUpload[]" value="<?php echo basename($result[$iDocsx]['doc_modele']); ?>" >
```